# Regex problem (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, quotes, expression

```
[quote=Username here]quoted text here[/quote]

Reply text here
```

I need a regular expression that stores the "Username here", "quoted text here" and "Reply text here" in a Array.

This expression needs to support nesting aswell. Eks:

```
[quote=Username2 here][quote=Username here]quoted text here[/quote]

Reply text here[/quote]

Reply text here
```

Comment: Regexes don't do nesting. They're not powerful enough. You should think about writing a proper stack-based parser that can do nesting arbitrarily deep.

Comment: What is the desired output from the nested example? Is there a limit on how deeply the quotes can be nested?

Answer (score 3):

This regex matches nested quote block (in group 1) with an additional last reply (in group 2):

```
(\[quote=[^]]*](?:(?R)|.)*\[/quote])(.*)
```

A little demo:

```
$text = '[quote=Username2 here][quote=Username here]quoted text[/quote]Reply text[/quote]More text';
preg_match('#(\[quote=[^]]*](?:(?R)|.)*\[/quote])(.*)#is', $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [quote=Username2 here][quote=Username here]quoted text[/quote]Reply text[/quote]More text
    [1] => [quote=Username2 here][quote=Username here]quoted text[/quote]Reply text[/quote]
    [2] => More text
)
```

A little explanation:

```
(                  # open group 1
  \[quote=[^]]*]   #   match '[quote= ... ]'
  (?:(?R)|.)*      #   recursively match the entire pattern or any character and repeat it zero or more times
  \[/quote]        #   match '[/quote]'
)                  # open group 1
(                  # open group 2
  .*               #   match zero or more trailing chars after thae last '[/quote]'
)                  # close group 2
```

But, using these recursive regex constructs supported by PHP might make ones head spin... I'd opt for a little parser like John Kugelman suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to return the values nested in some way or with quotes matched - which are impossible in a regex - you can just split on the parts you do not need:

```
preg_split('/(\[quote=|\[quote]|]|\[/quote])/', $yourstring);
```

Comment: That will not match arbitrary nested quote blocks.

Comment: As I said: some things you cannot do in a regular expression. Matching with nesting is one such thing. Very unfair to subtract points when I cannot get you the mathematically impossible.

Comment: Apologies, I though you posted a `preg_match(...)` solution, I now see it was a `preg_split(...)`. I will remove my down-vote.

Comment: Note that all regex implementations that support look-arounds, back references etc. cannot be considered mathematical "regular". And when an implementation does not support recursive constructs, you can still match a fixed number of nested tags by using look-aheads.

Comment: Ah well, your solution does win hands down.

Comment: @Matijs, perhaps, but although I know a bit of regex-trickery, I wouldn't quickly use a recursive regex construct in any code. Not even in one of the many pet-projects I'm working on! :)